# Ignore propertyplaceholder - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using the below statement to component scan all the beans defined in my applications dependent jar file -

```
@ImportResource({"classpath*:/META-INF/spring.xml"})
```

I have a bean defined in one of the spring.xml which is looking for a property placeholder **file:${service.propDir}**. The bean is no longer required but I can't remove it as it is part one of the jar file. Is there a way to ignore property placeholders , if not available in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Cleanly will be to remove it completely. However if you're still holding to it  using a `default` value should work for you:  `${service.propDir:defaultValue}`
Another option would be Using `@Conditional` or  `@Profile` [here is a good blog about these two](http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-conditional-annotation/)

Comment: Thanks @iamiddy. In this case however the placeholder is defined in a jar file shared by a different team and it can't be modified as it is used with appropriate values by other consumers of that team. Hence I guess conditional or profile annotation can't be used in this scenario.